# What does 'return-data' parameter mean when using ACTION_PICK intent?

Tags: android

I got the following code and I need to know what 'return-data' means. I can't find the documentation for any of these parameters

edit: I am retrieving the image from the stock android gallery

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 2);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputX", 600);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputY", 300);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getTempUri());
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 100);
```

Comment: "I can't find the documentation for any of these parameters" -- that's because none of those parameters are necessarily supported by any app. You will need to contact the developers of the million apps on the Play Store and ask them each whether they support `ACTION_PICK` and, if so, what extras they support, if any.

Comment: @CommonsWare i am getting the image from standard android gallary. why would I need to contact the millions of developers

Comment: "i am getting the image from standard android gallary" -- no, you are not. First, you are requesting the `MediaStore`. Anyone can write an activity that claims to support `ACTION_PICK` from the `MediaStore`, and the user is welcome to use any such activity. Second, there is no single "standard Android gallary", as different devices replace AOSP applications. So, not only do you need to contact the developers of Play Store apps that might have an activity, you need to contact all the world's device manufacturers and ask them if their "gallary" supports any extras, and if so, what they do.

Comment: Third, even if you happen to be on a device where the only available option is the "standard android gallary", that application has changed over the years. Assuming that undocumented and unsupported extras have themselves remained unchanged is unrealistic. In short, no talented developer would use the code you are using and expect reliable results.

Comment: @CommonsWare the code that i am using is used by many. its all over the internet and I don't think people just guessed it. i am sure there is a document detailing what each parameter does.

Comment: "i am sure there is a document detailing what each parameter does" -- only the source code, and that has changed in the AOSP itself, let alone in replacement "gallary" apps created by device manufacturers or other third parties.

Comment: @CommonsWare Well i guess then its a miracle we have come to know these parameters by chance

Comment: @CommonsWare instead of just chastising him for writing bad code, could also maybe tell us what a "talented" developer would actually do in situations such as his?

Comment: @Bhargav: There are many [image cropping libraries for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45).